# How to completely remove printer from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, canon-pixma

I'm having some issues with my Canon Pixma IP1900 printer - it doesn't respond to any OS requests. I am using Windows 7 x64 with additional Canon drivers and the printer used to work ok, but recently it doesn't anymore.

I've connected it to a second PC running on Win7 x86 and no additional Canon drivers and the printer worked again - not only did Windows find appropriate drivers all by itself, but everything else did work like a charm as well.

Now I assume that the problem is either the drivers (messed up by OS) or the OS itself. My idea is to completely remove Canon drivers and any data associated with the printer. **How do I do it?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://theitbros.com/remove-windows-vista7-printer-driver/) tutorial which explains how to use the Microsoft Management Console (MMC), to remove unwanted printer driver packages.

If that does not work for you, try using the **printui.exe** tool.

In an admin elevated command prompt type
`printui /s /t2`, be sure to remove the driver AND the package.

Here's how to do it, step-by-step:

1. Open a command line with administrative rights: Start->All Programs->Accessories->Command prompt; Right click -> Run As Administrator
2. Run the printui tool:  `printui /s /t2`
3. Try deleting the printers. If that doesn't work... (i.e., if removing the printers listed in the printui is not successful.)
4. Click *Start > Run > Services.msc*
5. Locate the Print Spooler service, and right-click > Properties > stop service.
6. Open My Computer and browse to `C:\Windows\System32\spool\Printers` (you will need to click "OK" to get access to the folder).
7. DELETE the contents of the folder you opened in step 6.
8. Go back to `services.msc` and Restart the Print Spooler service.
9. Go back into the printui utility (you might need to restart it using same method as above) and try removing printers again. This time it should work. If necessary, check the "Ports" tab and remove any TCP/IP ports that are associated with the old printer.
10. Last but not least, check other computers on your home network to see if any of those  map to the old printer, and remove these mappings

Comment: Well explained. Nice answer.

Comment: Everything you described worked (at least no errors were displayed). The problem is that after removing the drivers, rebooting and plugging in the printer I see the same problem - no connection with the printer can be established, though the printer works just fine with my x86 Windows 7.. How come? **What else can I do** / delete / reset ?

Comment: Have you tried a different port or cable?

Comment: Yes, I tried to change both..

Comment: It would help if you elaborate on the steps you took when installing the printer, perhaps your computer is not [set to automatically search online for drivers](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/make-windows-7-automatically-find-new-device-drivers/).

Comment: I removed the drivers (as you described), then plugged my printer in the usb. Next I removed the drivers again, changed settings to get the drivers from Windows Update, reboot, and plugged the printer again. Neither solution did work, no connection. I plugged a second printer, Pixma IP4500 and it's the same thing! So it's not the printer for 100%.. it's Windows or Canon drivers that are *messed up*. One thing I've noticed is that the Printer Status window has always the title 'USB001' .. no matter which USB port I plug the printer in..

Comment: Well... Next step should [be a System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/system-restore)

Comment: Nah man, this is enough of bull*$*@* for me. An interesting read for you: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EverythingsBrokenAndNobodysUpset.aspx Anyway, thank you for help.

Answer (score 4):

The only consistent way that I've been able to delete both the driver AND package is to:

1. Open the Start Menu.
2. Type "Command Prompt".
3. Under "Programs", right-click on "Command Prompt", click "Run as administrator", and accept the UAC prompt.
4. In the elevated Command Prompt, run `printui /s /t2` to open Print Server Properties on the Driver tab in elevated mode. Do not close the Command Prompt.
5. Select the driver you wish to uninstall.
6. Select "Remove...".
7. Select "Remove driver and driver package" but **leave the** "Deleting this printer driver package will remove it from the system. Are you sure you want to delete %driverName%?" **window open**.
8. In the elevated Command Prompt, run `net stop spooler`.
9. In the elevated Command Prompt, type but **don't run** `net start spooler`.
10. Click on the Command Prompt window and hover your cursor over the "Yes" button of the delete driver package window.
11. Press enter to execute the `net start spooler` command and as soon as you see the `The Print Spooler service is starting.` output click the "Yes" button of the delete driver package window.

Timing is key success.

Comment: Thank you for the simple command to stop the service spooler (beter than using `service.msc`)!

Comment: @MUY Belgium You can do this with `net [start | stop] ` and any service name. :)

Comment: Variation that reduces a few clicks: Part (A): open both Admin CMD shell and control panel _Devices and Printers_, restart\* Spooler service and immediately R-click the printer and Remove. Repeat until all desired printers are gone. Part (B): Now use `printui /s /t2` to remove the drivers and packages (no more need to start/stop spooler each time). (((\*Restart service as single command - `net stop spooler && net start spooler`)))