# Printer doesn't get orders from microsoft word or adobe reader

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, pdf, printing, printer

I have HP DeskJet 2540 series. At first, it printed everything but since a few days ago, it doesn't print anymore from Word or PDF files except from the Chrome browser.

The driver is up to date and I have tried to use a tool from HP's site to fix the printer problem with no result.

System: Windows 7 64-bit. I hope I can find the answer here.

Comment: What happens when you try to print, do you see the job in the spool?  Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the printer?

Comment: nothing happens, the icon in the notification area shows 0 documents pending.

Comment: and yes I have uninstaaled and reinstalled the driver again with the same result.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the default printer in word and your PDF software is the one you think it is?  Could be that you are printing to another printer.

Comment: It s the default, but I have discovered something important, I have made another windows account and tried to print from it and there was no problem, everything was okay, but the problem is still in my account!!

Comment: I'd guess the printer is not being completely removed from windows when you uninstall.  Refer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/525155/how-to-completely-remove-printer-from-windows-7) for an explanation of how to fully remove the printer.  I think if it works in another profile, you'll find it's likely driver related.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise I could print test reports etc but not MS documents.  I simply uninstalled the HP 2540 software (did not reinstall) and then went back and added printer and bingo it worked.  Looks like it's the software that trips the system up (Windows 8)